# How to combine strings that is extracted from .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

How can I combine this multiple strings to a single array in jquery?

So i extracted multiple texts after the  from ".ihf-grid-result-address" div.
But most of those texts are the same. I wanted to put them on a single array so I can use the ".unique function".

**Here is the code:**

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('.ihf-grid-result-address'), function (index, value) { 
 var str = jQuery(this).html();
 var output_holder = str.substr(str.indexOf("<br>") + 4);
var output = output_holder.split(',', 1)[0];

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    var innerHTML = jQuery('#post-0 > h1').html();
    innerHTML = '<span class="property-title">' + innerHTML + ' for ' + output + '</span>';
    jQuery('#post-0 > h1').html(innerHTML);
});

});
```

[image: console.log]

Thanks!

EDIT: I added the code and explanation on how it works.

Comment: well what is your code?

Comment: Show us what the `each` function looks like ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: are these all part of a 2d array?

Comment: Please don't post an image, but the object notation in text.

Comment: again not sure exactly what you are after but if you are attempting to get a unique set and are allowed to use underscore.... var unique = _.uniq(["Cameron Park", 
"Cameron Park", 
"Cameron Park",
"Cameron Park",
"Cameron Park",
"Auburn",
"Auburn"]);

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited my post and added the codes. Please check. thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mrk5p8ta/

Answer (score 0):

You can merge multiple arrays into one with:

```
arrays.reduce((previous, next) => previous.concat(next), []);
```

Or without arrow functions:

```
arrays.reduce(function (previous, next) { previous.concat(next) }, []);
```